# CNN - Proper way to adjust existing network (e.g. UNet) to fit the input/output size

Tags: deep-learning

I've implemented the original UNet-Architecture from its paper. It works with 572x572 images and predicts 388x388 images (original paper is without padding). I have used this network for another task which has 2048x1024 images as input to create the same sized (2048x1024) target. This fails, because the image size doesnt agree with the network architecture. So I saw on github a code which sets padding = 1 for all convolutions and everything works. Fine.

My question: Is that a common thing? "Randomly (maybe experimentally is better)" tweakin padding or stride parameters until the dimensions fit? But then it isn't the original UNet anymore, right?

I am glad for any advices, because I want to learn a good way for using existing networks in different challenges.

Best

Comment: Neural Networks are never made in stone.As long as you can train it properly using good data,  the network should perform well enough. There maybe a drop or even a rise in accuracy, but overall papers like these often provide a base shape of architecture. I have had to remove entire segments from large DNNs to fit space contrainsts and they performed quite well.

Comment: Ah ok. Is there any common way to alter these architectures? Or is that trivial (where (which layer maybe at the beginning or rather at the end) or which parameter I am altering) and a thing to find out experimentally?

Comment: DNNs are really black boxes when it comes to understanding the effect of an individual layer. So no I cannot recommend any common way. I usually remove at the end because the initial signals are strong but get weaker as get propagate so I want to maximize information extraction, but I have no strong facts to actually back this up. Testing your architectures is the best suggestion I can give.

Comment: Ok, thx for your comment :)